# Get element value in Option[Seq[Seq]]

Tags: scala

Im newbie in scala. Please help me this case.
I have class:

```
case class SubClass(
  name: String, age: Int    
)
```

Next, I have a Option instance:

```
Option[Seq[Seq[Seq[SubClass]]]
```

I add a element into the Option: `SubClass('no1',1)`

How can I get value `age` from Option above?

Comment: You can get all the ages from that deeply nested sequence thing as `theOption.toSeq.flatten.flatten.flatten.map(_.age)`. That gives you a `Seq[Int]`. But why is it nested like that and can you just ignore the structure of the sequences?

Comment: @Thilo: thanks! it comes from old source code which I need to maintain.

Comment: Maybe you should try to find out why it ended up like that, and fix it at the root (avoid unnecessary nesting)

Comment: Such type is quite weird (would wonder there is a design issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are way to many Seqs there, but here goes:

```
val stuff: Option[Seq[Seq[Seq[SubClass]]] = ???
stuf.get.head.head.head.age
```

So what is happening here is, you are getting what is inside the option, then get the first element of every Seq, then access to value age of SubClass.
This is really not a good idea because a lot of things can happen, the option could be a None, and that would break, and doing a head into one of those Seqs that could be empty would break as well.

So you have things like .getOrElse, and headOption that would cover those cases, and you could even map through all of those data structures, or a for, that would do the same as map but a bit more clean.

Since you are new to Scala I would recommend you to search a bit before going hands on work.

Anyways, hope this helped.

Comment: i get another error: Option[Seq[Seq[Seq[SubClass]]].get.head.head.head.age value get is not a member of Seq[Seq[Seq[SubClass]]]

Comment: Please don't use bare `get` and `head` calls: Use `map` and `flatten` to ensure it works in the case where the `Seq` is empty or the `Option` is `None`.